# Dimming energy with load cell

Tags: load-cell, dimming

I'm a lawyer with no technical background. I'm just a geek! :D

I wonder if it is possible without using a micro controller can a load cell dim the amount of energy supplied by a 3V battery?

The heavier the load the more energy is supplied and the lighter the load the less energy is supplied (I'm thinking max load ~35oz, min load ~7oz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is ‘yes’. When you say ‘dim the energy’ my interpretation is you want a voltage output proportional to the load?
If this is the case, you want a load cell amplifier. These are a common item, but for 3V operation it is not very common. Outputs of 0-5V or 0-10V are more likely.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! :D

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Most load cells give out a voltage analogous to the load. This output voltage is fed into an amplifier to bring the voltage up to useful levels - typically 0 to 5 V as this is common in microcontrollers and digital circuits.

It seems that you want to regulate the **power** to a load. This can be done by controlling the voltage (or current) supplied to the load. Power will be determined by \$ P = \frac {V^2} R \$ where \$V\$ is the voltage and \$R\$ is the load resistance and the power will be in watts (W). Energy is power by time - usually watt-seconds (Ws) or watt-hours (Wh).

Being constrained to 3 V supply will require some atypical design.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! :D